# collection in java(How to print objects separately)

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

If we are working on collection....for example ArrayList
then if ArrayList contains two types of objects(Integer and String) and we want to print them separately like integer objects in one group and string objects in another group.
Please anyone tell me how can we do this?

Comment: Please don't mix types in an `ArrayList`. If you must do something like that, I would create a composite pojo type class and make both types `Optional` fields.

Comment: @akshma this is very broad question , and unclear to understand. can you please refine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List<Object>` but in that case you need to be careful. Have to check which instance it is and cast it accordingly.

See below example:

***EDIT***

added list for each group

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add(2);

    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object o : list) {
        if (o instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("String is: " + o);
            strList.add((String) o);
        }
        if (o instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("Integer is: " + o);
            intList.add((Integer) o);
        }
    }
```

**OP:**

```
String is: a
Integer is: 2
```

Comment: Thank you Shubhendy Pramanik. But can you please tell me..why this program is showing error:         import java.util.*;
class Collection1
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   ArrayList l=new ArrayList();
   l.add(1);
   l.add("a");
   l.add("3");
   Iterator itr=l.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext())
   {
      Object o=itr.next();
     if(o instanceOf Integer)
  {
 System.out.println(o);
     }
   }
   }
  }

Comment: @AkshmaMittal what error are you getting? Pls post.

Comment: Using this code you will always have to check the object of value. and It results in code increase. So not recommended to use. If you have only selected type of Object (2-3) then you can use, but for large amount of data where different type of object values are used you cannot use.

Comment: Variable Declaration is not allowed here.(where i write instanceOf Integer)

Comment: I got the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be below program can help you , it will dynamically create separate list of a type depending upon the object in your main list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SeparateType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(101);
        arrayList.add("Hello");
        arrayList.add(102);
        arrayList.add("World");
        arrayList.add(103);
        arrayList.add("String3");
        arrayList.add(104);
        arrayList.add("String4");
        arrayList.add(1.0);

        for (Map.Entry<Class,ArrayList<Object>> entry : convertToSeprateType(arrayList).entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey().getSimpleName()+ " List values : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static <T> HashMap<Class,ArrayList<Object>>  convertToSeprateType(ArrayList<Object> arrayList) {
        HashMap<Class,ArrayList<Object>> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
        final T val;
        for(Object object:arrayList) {
            if(hashMap.containsKey(object.getClass())) {
                hashMap.get(object.getClass()).add(object);
            }else {
                ArrayList<T> list=new ArrayList<T>();
                list.add((T) object);
                hashMap.put(object.getClass(), (ArrayList<Object>) list);

            }

        }
        return hashMap;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Integer List values : [101, 102, 103, 104]
Double List values : [1.0]
String List values : [Hello, World, String3, String4]
```